# DataGrid with items from PowerShell very slow when source size large

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, wpfdatagrid

Here's a simple WPF program (most of the code is in the code-behind):

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTextBlockInlineDataGridPSProcessSource.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTextBlockInlineDataGridPSProcessSource"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

using static System.Console;

namespace WpfTextBlockInlineDataGridPSProcessSource
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault());

            runspace.Open();

            var ps = PowerShell.Create();

            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            // var result = ps.AddScript("get-process").Invoke();

            var result = ps.AddScript("get-process | select-object -first 20").Invoke();


            WriteLine(result.Count);


            if (result.All(elt => elt.BaseObject is Process))
            {

                var data_grid = new DataGrid()
                {
                    ItemsSource = result,

                    IsReadOnly = true,

                    AutoGenerateColumns = false
                };

                data_grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
                {
                    Header = "ProcessName",
                    Binding = new Binding("ProcessName"),
                });

                var text_block = new TextBlock();

                var scroll_viewer = new ScrollViewer();

                scroll_viewer.Content = text_block;

                text_block.Inlines.Add(data_grid);

                text_block.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

                var dock_panel = new DockPanel();

                dock_panel.Children.Add(scroll_viewer);

                Content = dock_panel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need the [System.Management.Automation.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation.dll/) nuget package to build this test program.

Here's what it looks like when run:

[image]

Note that the `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` is set to the result of a `PowerShell` command.

In that case, we're only displaying 20 `Process` objects in the `DataGrid`.

With only 20 items, the program opens quickly and is responsive.

If we change this line:

```
var result = ps.AddScript("get-process | select-object -first 20").Invoke();
```

to the following:

```
var result = ps.AddScript("get-process").Invoke();
```

the program becomes non-responsive. Note that on my system, there are over 370 processes in the list; results may vary on your system.

How can the program be made to be responsive in the case of a large amount of items?

Please note that the particular arrangement of the WPF items:

`DockPanel` -> `ScrollViewer` -> `TextBlock` -> `Inline` -> `DataGrid`

is meant to simulate another program that this one is meant to demonstrate the issue in. So that's why it's setup in this way.

If there aren't enough processes running on your system to experience the slow down, you can also use something like the following:

```
var result = ps.AddScript("get-process | select-object -first 20; get-process | select-object -first 20; get-process | select-object -first 20").Invoke();
```

To simulate a larger number of processes. (Consider getting the count to over 300.)

Comment: Why do you create `DataGrid` from code behind?

Comment: Is it necessary to follow this arrangement `DockPanel -> ScrollViewer -> TextBlock -> Inline -> DataGrid`? There are lot of processing in your code against the control's capacity. You are taking many unnecessary controls and combining them. This can be achieved with very simple UI and code behind.

Comment: if it's just to retrieve a list of executable's can you call tasklist instead?

Comment: @GaurangDave The issue has been solved. See answer.

Comment: @lloyd The issue has been solved. See answer.

Comment: @dharmatech Sorry but this is not solution. You just got work around to issue you faced. I do not know what are you trying to achieve but now height of Grid won't exceed 800 so there is no multi resolution support. You can have better solution to this if you can arrange your UI structure properly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `MaxHeight` of the `DataGrid` solved the issue:

```
var data_grid = new DataGrid()
{
    ItemsSource = result,

    IsReadOnly = true,

    MaxHeight = 800,

    AutoGenerateColumns = false
};
```

It's blazing fast now!

One theory is that, without a `MaxHeight`, the whole `DataGrid` is shown, thus turning off virtualization. `MaxHeight` causes a `ScrollViewer` to engage after a certain height is surpassed, which seems to allow for virtualization.

Comment: This is not proper way to achieve this. It will be more faster if you decrease `MaxHeight`.